# How to not process commands in discord.py if the channel if private?

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

My code :

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author.id == self.bot.user.id:
            return
        if message.channel.type == discord.ChannelType.private:
            await message.channel.send("Vous devez être dans un serveur pour realiser cette commande !")
            return
```

but it doesn't work, it's recognise that is was a private channel and it send the right message but it also process the command and send the answer ...

Answer (score -1):

Don't include `bot.process_commands(message)` in the if code block which runs if the channel is private. Try this:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author.id == self.bot.user.id:
            bot.process_commands(message)
            return
        if message.channel.type == discord.ChannelType.private:
            await message.channel.send("Vous devez être dans un serveur pour realiser cette commande !")
            return
        #Don't add bot.process_commands(message) here.
```

Don't add `bot.process_commands(message)` outside the if block because if you do then it will run even if it is private.

Comment: I already don't have this command but it's not working

Comment: If I put bot process command, the bot answer 2 times

Comment: @Alex, where are you adding the `bot.process_commands()` line? It will answer two times if you put it outside the `if` block.

Comment: I don't have bot.process_commands() in my code

Comment: @Alex then what are you talking about? What, where and how are the commands processed? Are they after the second `return`? If they're there, it's because the second `return` means "go to the next part of code after the `if` and *process the commands*.

Comment: Ok, thx for explaining was return is doing